# Search lists for a sequence

Tags: python, list, parsing

listIf I have a list of lists.  Where each sub list is different from the next, sometimes even empty.

```
    list[0]=['This','is','the','sequence']
    list[1]=['This','is','another','sequence']
    list[2]=[]
    list[n]=[a,b,c,d]
```

How can i search the lists and correctly identify when list[n] occurs.  (IE identify a,b,c occuring then extract d.)

I tried

```
for lists in my_list[1:]:
          if not lists:
             continue
          if (lists[0]=='a') & (lists[1]=='b') &(lists[2]=='c'):
             extracted_variable = lists[3]
```

However I receive 'list index out of range' for the empty lists.  What functions can work to my advantage?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
for l in lists:
    if l[:3] == ['a', 'b', 'c'] and len(l) > 3:
        print l[3]
```

Explanation:

The reason you get 'list index out of range' on empty lists is because you try to access an index that is out of range (lists[0] == 'a'). The syntax I used `l[:3]` gives you a sub list of the list with first 3 items. for example this `[1,2,3,4][:3]` will return this `[1,2,3]`.
For empty lists there's no problem because it will just return an empty list.

So in the way I used above we just take a sub list of 3 items and check if its a list of `["a", "b", "c"]`. if so we make sure there's at least one more item in list (by checking len() of the list) and if so we print it.

Also you shouldn't use the keyword 'list' in your code for variable names, but I assume it might be just an example for the question.

You should read more about lists in python and how to use them (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)

Answer (score 0):

first check length of list is greater 2 and apply your check conditions as follows:
using for loop:

```
my_list = [['This', 'is', 'the', 'sequence'], ['This', 'is', 'another', 'sequence'], [], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
for lst in my_list:
    if len(lst) > 2 and lst[0] == 'a' and lst[1] == 'b' and lst[2] == 'c':
        extracted_variable = lst[3]
        print extracted_variable
```

using list comprehension:

```
my_list = [['This', 'is', 'the', 'sequence'], ['This', 'is', 'another', 'sequence'], [], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
a = [lst[3:] for lst in my_list if len(lst) > 2 and lst[0] == 'a' and lst[1] == 'b' and lst[2] == 'c']
print a[0][0]
```

output:

```
d
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the technique of the sliding/rolling window:

```
from itertools import islice

all_lists = [

    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6,5,4,7,8],
    [7,8,9,4,4],
    [1,],
    ["a","b","c"],

]

## All the lists you want to find
## We use tuples becuase lists are not hashable. You also can do this tuple([1,2,3])
target_list_1 = ("a","b","c")
target_list_2 = (1,2,3)

## A counter for your target lists you want to find
counter_dict = {
    target_list_1 : 0,
    target_list_2 : 0,
}


generator = islice(all_lists, len(all_lists) )

for item in generator:

    ## You can add as many checking conditions as you want, you may 
    ## also use switch statment here, whatever you want

    if item == list(target_list_1):
        counter_dict[target_list_1] +=1

    if item == list(target_list_2):
        counter_dict[target_list_2] +=1


print counter_dict
```

Output:

```
{ 
    ('a', 'b', 'c') : 1, 
    (1, 2, 3)       : 1
}
```